# how to Manage app and data on a device (Block, Wipe and others) in ibm mobilefirst 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

**How to Manage app and data on a device (Block, Wipe and others) in ibm mobilefirst 8.0?**

Following options are available in Mobilefirst 7.1:

Managing app distribution (using the Application Center)
Managing app versions (using the Operations Console)
Managing app access (using the Operations Console)
Managing usage, performance, warnings and errors (using the Analytics Console)
Managing data access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you will take a tour of the MobileFirst Operations Console in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0. See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/product-overview/components/console/

> Managing data access / Managing app access

I assume you are referring to "remote disable". This is available from the application screen in the console. Select the desired registered application from the sidebar navigation and under the **Management** tab you will see a **Application Access** title.

> Managing usage, performance, warnings and errors (using the Analytics Console)

Unsurprisingly, this is available from the Analytics console as before.
Learn more about Analytics console here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/analytics/console/

> Managing app distribution (using the Application Center)

This has not changed and it not related to MobileFirst Foundation 8.0. You do this through the AppCenter console as before. AppCenter did not change between 7.1 and 8.0.

> Managing app versions

In previous versions you would have upped the version value in application-descriptor.xml. In v8.0 instead whenever you want to release a new point release, i.e. 1.1 or 2.0 etc, you need to register another app versions, either using the MobileFirst CLI or directly via the console.

---

I suggest that you will start getting familiar with the product...

- Product overview: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/product-overview/
- Upgrading/Migrating: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/
- Application development: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/

Comment: How to handle these events **Enabled** , **Disabled** , **Active** in client side ? I am getting alert **Application Disabled** with close button. but how to handle it in client side ?

Comment: What is there to manage on the client side? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: After Disabling the app from console, I am getting alert Application Disabled.. but still app is moving to next screen.  My question is how to handle these events in client side so my app can't move to next screen.

Comment: Please read about the feature. What is disabled is the communication to the server, not stuff in the app.